# Retrieve hierarchical data object with Where clause in root table in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, hierarchical-data

I have a little project in which I have a main table which is the root of a hierarchy of tables, and this table has an "ID" and an "instance ID", which both represents a primary key. This is because I want to keep tracking of changes if there are any changes in the row. Also, in this root table I have an attribute to mark rows as "deleted".

What I'm trying to do is the following query: given a single "ID" (the first one) request I'd like to get the one single row that has the attribute "deleted" to 0 (which means that it is the current active row, because those marked as 1 are part of an historic that is stored in the same table) and also the subsequent attributes of the hierarchy.

For example, If I have a table called Animal which has a child table called Dog, I'd like to recover the entire Dog object by his "ID", which is a foreign key from Animal. Hibernate has a method that is able to do this, but the problem is that if I want to use it I can't use the Where clause, and if I write the query I have to explicitly write the joins depending on the child object class that I want to get.

```
// This is what I have
public Dog returnAnimalData(String ID) {
    List<Dog> dogs = hibernate.getCurrentSession().get(Dog.class, ID);
    for (Dog dog : dogs) {
        if(dog.getMarkAsDeleted().equals(0)){
            return dog;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// This is what I would like
public Dog returnAnimalData(String ID) {

    @Where(clause="deleted=0")
    Dog dog = hibernate.getCurrentSession().get(Dog.class, ID);

    // Or 

    Dog dog = hibernate.getCurrentSession().get(Dog.class, ID, 'where deleted = 0');

    return dog;
}
```

EDIT:

An example:

Animal has ID, InstanceID, deletedFlag and typeOfAnimal
Dog has ID, InstanceID and Name, and Dog extends Animal
Cat has ID, InstanceID, Name and isFat, and Cat extends Animal

The process would be like this:

```
Ask for animal 1
 -> Animal 1 is a Dog
 -> search Dog with ID=1 and deletedFlag=0
 -> retrieve Dog (IDs, deletedFlag, animalType, Name)
Ask for animal 2
 -> Animal 2 is a Cat
 -> search Cat with ID=2 and deletedFlag=0
 -> retrieve Cat (IDs, deletedFlag, animalType, Name, isFat)
```

The thing is to resolve this query without worrying about the number of child classes of Animal, something like "SELECT animal FROM CONCRETE_ANIMAL_TABLE where deletedFlag=0", where CONCRETE_ANIMAL_TABLE could be the name of table Dog, Cat, etc. I'll try to do Naros's answer first.

If I find the answer I'll post it, because I think it is a very interesting problem and maybe it should help to understand how to manage hierarchies with Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use either HQL/JPQL to get your `Dog` or the JPA Criteria API.  Since you're using the native Hibernate API, I'll illustrate HQL in this case:

```
public List<Dog> getDogsByDeletedFlag(boolean deletedFlag) {
  return hibernate.getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery( "SELECT d FROM Dog d WHERE d.deleted = :deletedFlag" )
        .setParameter( "deletedFlag", deletedFlag )
        .getResultList();
}
```

The methods `Session#get` and `Session#load` are meant only for fetching an instance of a particular entity type by identifeir, not for potentially fetching a list of possible results.

If you're interested in only fetching the first hit and not all possible rows, you could impose limit constraints on the above query, such as:

```
public Dog getFirstDogByDeletedFlag(boolean deletedFlag) {
  return hibernate.getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery( "SELECT d FROM Dog d WHERE d.deleted = :deletedFlag" )
        .setParameter( "deletedFlag", deletedFlag )
        .setMaxResults( 1 ) // only gets the first hit
        .getSingleResult(); 
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you're wanting to use a single method to obtain polymorphic classes, all you'd need to do is to pass in the appropriate values to accomplish just that:

```
public <T> T getFirstAnimalByDeletedFlag(Class<T> clazz, boolean deletedFlag) {
  // NOTE: We assume that the class name is also the entity name.
  // Since you can explicitly name entities, e.g. @Entity(name = "MyName"), 
  // you'd need to pass this String value separately if you use this.

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append( "FROM " ).append( clazz.getName() ).append( " o " );
  sb.append(" WHERE o.deleted = :deletedFlag" );

  return hibernate.getCurrentSession()
         .createQuery( sb.toString(), clazz )
         .setParameter( "deletedFlag", deletedFlag )
         .setMaxResults( 1 )
         .getSingleResult();
}
```

Then all you need to do is call it: `#getFirstAnimalByDeletedFlag( Dog.class, true )` or `#getFirstAnimalByDeletedFlag( Cat.class, true )`.

Comment: But I have a little doubt here: when you say "SELECT d FROM Dog d...", that "d" variable has all superclass attributes, meaning the Animal attributes and the Dog attributes? Because what I'm trying to do is to define this method to be able to retrieve whatever subclass I ask. Am I able to retrieve, with the same query, a complete Dog and Cat? Anyways, I'll edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: There are numerous ways to accomplish what you ask for, what I included in my post is just one.  If I were developing this, I'd likely simply have an abstract repository class that takes a `Class<T>` constructor argument to and then a repository implementation for `Dog` and one for `Cat`.  From business code, I'd either then query a `CatRepository` or `DogRepository` based on what I needed.  The method would be shared and I wouldn't need to pass the `Class<T>` as a method argument.